# JSON object date to date javascript date format symfony

Tags: javascript, php, json, symfony, date

I am javing a problem with date object, my problem is, I return an object without problem and it do `JSON.parse` perfectly, the problem is here I have this code

```
var citas = JSON.parse(data.citas);
$.each(citas, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(value.fecha);
});
```

Here is my `console.log()` result

```
Object {id: 1, fecha: Object, hora: "17:45:32", confirmada: true, informe: ""…}
Object {timezone: Object, offset: 7200, timestamp: 1502920800}
```

the result is perfect but i want to conver value.fecha to the real date on my database I mean this example is 2017-08-17 and I want to transform the object date to this date, any idea??

Answer (score 0):

thanks `new Date(value.fecha.timestamp*1000);` is the solution, i was trying `new Date(value.fecha.timestamp);` without multiplicate